# Using SQL LIKE operator like a Stored Procedure paramater

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to use LIKE %...% in a stored procedure but I'm not sure how to use the incoming variable in the operator. For example, I'm doing this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetGameByName(IN gameName varchar(255))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM game
 WHERE gameTitle LIKE '% + gameName + %';
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

but when I call it like this

```
CALL GetGameByName('Creed');
```

It is returning nothing (I DO have a game with gameTitle "Assassin's Creed"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED due to issue in comment - the solution is now `WHERE gameTitle LIKE CONCAT('%',gameName,'%')`

===== Previous Answer =====

It looks to me like you forgot quotation marks.  Instead of `WHERE gameTitle LIKE '% + gameName + %';`, you should probably do `WHERE gameTitle LIKE '%' + gameName + '%';`

The way you have it set up, you are feeding the incorrect generic text `'%gameTitle%'` into the query, instead of what you really want, which is something like: `'%Creed%'`.

Comment: When I change it to your recommendation I get "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ gameName + '%'; END' at line 5"

Comment: Hm, not sure why.  Maybe try using `CONCAT('%',gameName,'%')` instead of `'%' + gameName + '%';`