# SQL Stored Procedure LIKE Operation for Parameters Error On MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i want to create stored procedure with LIKE operation but getting error and the answers[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594075/using-sql-like-operator-like-a-stored-procedure-paramater)[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380196/using-like-operator-with-stored-procedure-parameters/16381750) that i saw was outdated for current version. How can i write the procedure correctly

Getting same error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' AND; `brand` LIKE '%' + @Brand+ '%' AND; `description' at line 2

Tried these:

```
BEGIN
 `name` LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' AND
 `brand` LIKE '%' + @Brand+ '%' AND
 `description` LIKE '%' + @Desc + '%' AND
 `type` LIKE '%' + @Type + '%';
END


BEGIN
 `name` LIKE CONCAT('%', @Name, '%') AND
 `brand` LIKE CONCAT('%', @Brand, '%') AND
 `description` LIKE CONCAT('%', @Desc, '%') AND
 `type` LIKE CONCAT('%', @Type, '%');
END
```

doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Screenshot:
[image: screen]
[image: error]

Comment: What actually do you want to do? (select, update something, insert to another table...) in your BEGIN-END section you just wrote partial query , looks like the where part and not a full query

Comment: Besides two direct issues with the code that I flagged as duplicates, I second to @shushu304 : I do not get what you try to accomplish with your code. Pls ask a new question after fixing the two issues if you need further help!